# Why quadratic plots giving error with matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to plot as below:-

```
x=0:0.1:1;
plot(x,2*x-x^2);
```

Why does this give the following error:-

```
Error using  ^ 
Inputs must be a scalar and a square matrix.
To compute elementwise POWER, use POWER (.^) instead.
```

The objective is to plot a quadratic function only. SO i modified the above as follows:-

```
x=0:0.1:1;
plot(x,2*x-x*x);
```

The error persisted:-

```
Error using  * 
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.
```

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: Do as the error message tells you; i.e. use `plot(x,2*x-x.^2)`. Note the dot before the `^` to compute element-wise

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. My Bad! And why does the second method does not work? I figured it's the same reason as above.

Comment: Because you're trying to multiply a 1 x 11 vector with a 1 x 11 vector, which is not allowed. You could multiply a 1 x 11 with a 11 x 1 vector (eg. the transpose of `x`), which would give a scalar (3.85).

Comment: It's the same problem--you need to use `x.*x`. Whenever you want to perform element-wise operations on arrays in MATLAB, you must use `.`; otherwise MATLAB assumes you want to perform matrix multiplication. `x^2` and `x*x` are interpreted as matrix multiplication, which makes no sense because the dimensions disagree. `x.^2` and `x.*x` perform multiplication element-by-element.

Comment: I think this question should either be closed, because its a bit trivial, or properly answered. @eigenchris, your comment basically is an answer. Would you care to upgrade it?

Answer (score 1):

You want either

```
x=0:0.1:1;
plot(x,2*x-x.^2);
```

or

```
x=0:0.1:1;
plot(x,2*x-x.*x);
```

---

MATLAB automatically uses the `*` operator for matrix multipilcation when both operands are arrays, and uses the `^` for matrix multiplication when the left operand is an array. This applies to both one- and two-dimensional arrays.

`x*x` and `x^2` are trying to matrix-multiply a 1x11 array by a 1x11 array, which makes no sense, hence the `Inner matrix dimensions must agree.` error.

To perform element-wise operations on arrays, you must prefix the operator with a `.`. For example, `x.*x` performs element-wise multiplication and `x.^2` performs element-wise exponentiation.

See below:

```
>> A = magic(3)

A =

     8     1     6
     3     5     7
     4     9     2

>> A*A % or A^2 do matrix multiplication

ans =

    91    67    67
    67    91    67
    67    67    91

>> A.*A % or A.^2 do element-wise multiplication, (the square of each element)

    64     1    36
     9    25    49
    16    81     4
```